# browse kubernetes network form outside

Tags: kubernetes

I'm running a kubernetes cluster on AWS using Weave with a private topology. I have some multi-node applications (like Spark) that have a UI web page. I can expose that via a load balancer, but all the links to the workers, etc. use the k8s local ip addresses. Is it possible (via kubectl proxy or otherwise) to temporarily "go inside" the k8s network from a browser on my laptop, so that all the k8s internal ips work as expected? I'm not looking to expose everything to the outside, but to be able to temporarily browse for things from my laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [weave expose](https://www.weave.works/documentation/net-latest-using-weave/net-latest-host-network-integration/) to expose weave Subnet.

Comment: That looks exactly like what I'm looking for. Where do I run weave expose? On a host? On my laptop? Do I need to install some utility to use weave on the terminal?

Comment: on host. since you use weave cni, `weave` command should be already available there.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `kubectl port-forward my-container-name localport:serviceport` on your laptop (where service port is the port exposed by your WebUI service). Then you should be able to browse to `localhost:localport` and everything should work as expected.

Alternatively you may need to SSH into one of the private nodes via a bastion host.